# Help me out in this integration

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Prove that $\sin(wx)\cos(wx)\,dx$ from $0$ to $\pi/w = -2/3w$

I have solved and solved and solved but keep getting zero.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Michael Rybkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is 0.

$\sin{wx}\cos{wx}=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2wx}$

So the integral is

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/w} \sin{2 w x} \ dx$$

Let $u=2wx$. Then $du=2wdx$ or $dx=\frac{du}{2w}$

We must also multiply our endpoints by $2w$to get them with respect to $u$.

So we have:

$$\frac{1}{4w}\int_0^{2\pi} \ \sin{u} \ du$$

Integrating the sine from 0 to 2$\pi$ is a full cycle. The region of area is congruent to the area under the curve from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.  So we canchange the limits to get :

$$\frac{1}{4w}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin{u} \ du$$

The sine is  an odd function, i.e. $\sin{-x}=-\sin{x}$

So for every bit of area we have above the x axis and the curve there is equal and oppositely signed area on the other side of the y axis. So the sum of the area under the curve must be 0.

We get this solely from geometric considerations, no calculation necessary. So the area is 0.

Comment: I also got zero but the I seem not to understand why the -2/3w

Comment: Can you give more detail? I think some information is missing. Check all the terms and the limits. Are there exponents missing?

Comment: There is none. The question was given by our Engineering mathematics Lecturer in school to go and try it at home. I have tried using 4 different ways but all to no avail. I still get zero

Comment: It's 0. I've even tried raising sin to a power and modifying the endoints. None of those gets you the -2/3w

Comment: I think there must me a mistake somewhere in the question. All the answers I got using different methods is 0